# Transform SUMIFS into SUMIF (or anything else) to make it work with ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, sumifs

I am trying to automatize properly a spreadsheet (i.e. not having to manually expand formulas) and I can't figure out a workaround when it comes to SUMIFS.

As far as I searched online, I can't use either SUMIFS or QUERY in an ARRAYFORMULA.
I read it was possible to do it through SUMIF but haven't succeeded.

Rather than having that on each line:
`=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"="&A2,B:B,"<="&B2)`

I am trying to have 1 formula on the first line. I thought the one below would work, but it didn't.
`={"total_sessions_per_install";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A)),SUMIF(A:A&B:B,"="&A2:A&"<="&B2:B,C:C),IFERROR(0/0)))}`

Here is a demo file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lI_XABPwXb4Gc_cb9gjBrDKMaL_Aj0RLS3BTISMLyhA/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))>=ROW(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))*(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))), 
 INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), 0)), ROW(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))^0))
```

Comment: And this one is pretty classy! Definitely saving it for future use cases!

Answer (score 1):

or slower one if you got a lot of blank rows:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(ROW(B2:B79), "<="&ROW(B2:B79), C2:C79)-
 SUMIF(A2:A79, "<"&A2:A79, C2:C79))
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to add DATEVALUE for the first column in my real spreadsheet, but this solution is a nice workaround!